# Round Timestamp to nearest Hour in teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

How do I convert a Timestamp to the hour in teradata?

For ex

```
'2020-12-07 11:25:00.000000' to '2020-12-07 11:00:00.000000' 
'2020-12-07 11:45:00.000000' to '2020-12-07 11:00:00.000000'
```

Answer (score 2):

Gordon's solution might not work and return a DATE instead of a TIMESTAMP, depending on a global dbscontrol setting.

Then the most efficient solution is

```
ts - extract(minute from ts)*interval '1' minute
   - extract(second from ts)*interval '1' second
```

Needs more resources:

```
to_timestamp(to_char(ts, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh'), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh')
```

Comment: to_timestamp(to_char(ts, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh'), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh') works but it returns hour in 12 hour format. I even used hh24 but it still doesnt work. Is there a way to get the Hour in 24 Hour format?

Comment: Ops, correct, but HH24 should work. Does #1 fail?

Comment: The first one works well, the second one however isnt converting even after passing HH24

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`trunc()`](https://docs.teradata.com/r/kmuOwjp1zEYg98JsB8fu_A/5HG5LFgQ_BL_pARR%7ERQPHw):

```
select trunc(col, 'HH24')
```

Comment: This only returns the date not the timestamp

Answer (score 0):

If you want to round then you can add 30 minutes to your timestamp and then use `trunc` as follows:

```
select trunc(ts_col + interval '30' minute, 'HH')
```